# Shell Scripting: Generating output file name in script and then writing to it

Tags: shell

I have a shell script where a user passes different sizes as command line arguments. For each of those sizes, I want to perform some task, then save the output of that task into a .txt file with the size in the name.

1. How can I take the command line passed and make that part of a stringname for the output file? I save the output file in a directory specified by another command line argument. Perhaps an example will clear it up.
2. In the foor lop, the i value represents the command line argument I need to use, but $$i doesnt work.

./runMe arg1 arg2 outputDir [size1 size2 size3...]

```
for ((i=4; i<$#; i++ ))
do
    ping -s $$i google.com >> $outputDir/$$iresults.txt
done
```

I need to know how to build the $outputDir/$$iresults.txt string. Also, the ping -s $$i doesnt work. Its like I need two levels of replacement. I need to replace the $[$i] inner $i with the value in the loop, like 4 for ex, making it $4. Then replace $4 with the 4th command line argument!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indirection uses the `!` substitution prefix:

```
echo "${!i}"
```

But you should be using a bare for after shifting the earlier ones out:

```
shift
shift
for f
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Ok I understand the shiffting, but how should I use it to build the string?

Comment: The shifting does not build the string. The for loop builds the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ARG in $@; do
  $COMMAND  > ${ARG}.txt
done
```

Comment: I dont really understand the $COMMAND part?

Comment: And how would I concatenate a string with the ${ARG}.txt like: {ARG}results.txt

Comment: `$COMMAND` is your command. Substitute it with anything at all: for example, `ping -s ...`. As for concatenation: yes, `${ARG}results.txt` will do. Given argument 23 it produces 23results.txt.

Comment: You might want to manipulate the arguments so they doesn't have invalid or unintuitive characters. For example: `ARG=$(echo -n '$ARG' |sed 's/[ \t]/_/g')`